# Xml goes blank, when updated with Groovy XmlParser

Tags: groovy

I am quite new to groovy and seek your help.
I want to read an delta xml file and update master xml file based on a name attribute. Both the xml files are of same structure. I am trying to update attribute values in the master xml file. But the master file goes blank once, the file is updated. I am not sure where I am wrong.

Below is the xml structure:

```
<item-descriptor name="user" cache-mode="simple" item-cache-size="3000" query-cache-size="1000"  item-cache-timeout="900000"  query-expire-timeout="60000" />
<item-descriptor name="contactInfo" cache-mode="simple" item-cache-size="10000" query-cache-size="1000"  item-cache-timeout="900000"  query-expire-timeout="60000" />
```

Below is the code for this:

```
def templatexmlConfig = new XmlParser().parse(templateConfigFile)
def basexmlConfig = new XmlSlurper().parse(baseConfigFile)
def templateItemDesNode = templatexmlConfig.'item-descriptor'
def baseItemDesNode=basexmlConfig.'item-descriptor'
templateItemDesNode.each()
{
    Map bindings=[:]
    def nameAttr=it.attribute('name')
    it.attributes().each{attrName,attrValue->
    if(!attrName.equals('name'))
    {
             bindings.put(attrName,attrValue)
    }}

    if(baseItemDesNode.find{ it.@name.text().equals(nameAttr)}.size()!=0)
    {   
             bindings.each
             {   
                 def a=it.key
                 def v=it.value
             baseItemDesNode.find{ it.@name.text().equals(nameAttr)}.@'a'="${v}"                                             }

    }                           
}
new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(outputFile)).print(basexmlConfig)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, given two example xml documents:

```
def templateXml = '''<xml>
                    |  <item-descriptor name="a" cache-mode="r1" item-cache-size="1"/>
                    |  <item-descriptor name="b" cache-mode="r2" item-cache-size="2" new-attr="tim"/>
                    |  <item-descriptor name="z" cache-mode="r3" item-cache-size="3"/>
                    |</xml>'''.stripMargin() ;
def baseXml = '''<xml>
                |  <item-descriptor name="b" cache-mode="o1" item-cache-size="10"/>
                |  <item-descriptor name="c" cache-mode="o2" item-cache-size="11"/>
                |  <item-descriptor name="a" cache-mode="o3" item-cache-size="12"/>
                |</xml>'''.stripMargin()
```

We can parse these (Using XmlParser for both, you had parser for one, and slurper for the other):

```
def templatexmlConfig = new XmlParser().parseText( templateXml )
def basexmlConfig = new XmlParser().parseText( baseXml )
```

And then get the `item-descriptor` nodes (as you had it)

```
def templateItemDesNode = templatexmlConfig.'item-descriptor'
def baseItemDesNode = basexmlConfig.'item-descriptor'
```

Then, loop through the template `item-descriptors`, generate a map of non-name attributes (using `findAll` is easier than the loop you had), and replace all nodes on the node in `baseXml` with the same name:

```
templateItemDesNode.each() { tidn ->
  Map bindings = tidn.attributes().findAll { it.key != 'name' }
  def nameAttr = tidn.@name
  baseItemDesNode.find { b -> b.@name == nameAttr }?.with { node ->
    bindings.each { a, v ->
      node.@"$a" = v
    }
  }
}
```

And for this easily runnable example, just print out the Xml:

```
println new StringWriter().with { sw ->
  new XmlNodePrinter( new PrintWriter( sw ) ).print(basexmlConfig)
  sw.toString()
}
```

And when run, the above prints out:

```
<xml>
  <item-descriptor name="b" cache-mode="r2" item-cache-size="2" new-attr="tim"/>
  <item-descriptor name="c" cache-mode="o2" item-cache-size="11"/>
  <item-descriptor name="a" cache-mode="r1" item-cache-size="1"/>
</xml>
```

Obviously for your working code, you would need to go back to using `parse` on the `XmlParsers` to parse your files rather than the Strings I have here, and change the output back to writing to a file...

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and the code Tim. I am going to make changes in my code and test it. Will let you. Thanks.

Comment: @user1470220 Cool.  Fingers crossed :-)

Comment: Thanks Tim. I have tried your piece of code and it works perfect. Thanks a lot. Can you please suggest me a good book for Groovy? I am a beginner and want to build my basics.

Comment: [Groovy In Action 2](http://www.manning.com/koenig2/) is currently in Early access.  The first version is worth having too, but it's based on a very old version of Groovy. I've got [Groovy Recipies](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Groovy-Recipes-Greasing-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/0978739299) as well, and that's good (although just as out of date as GIA#1).  If you could accept the answer (there should be a check mark for you to click up near the top of the answer), that would be cool too :-)  Have fun!